# Get AD object attribute using ASP VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, active-directory

Does anyone know how to obtain an attribute from an AD object using VB running on an ASP web application?

I'm currently trying to use `System.DirectoryServices` but not having much luck.

```
ActiveDirectorysAMaccountname = Environment.UserName.TrimStart("DOMAIN\")

Dim search As New DirectorySearcher()
search.Filter = ("sAMAccountName=" + ActiveDirectorysAMaccountname)
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID")
Dim result As SearchResult = search.FindOne()
```

The above does return a result but it's in the form of `byte()`, instead of what I expected which would be the `objectGUID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `objectGuid` is stored in binary form so you're getting the expected result. You can pass it to the `Guid` constructor to get the strongly typed version.